# Priority Queue in JavaScript, I am not able to add more than one node

Tags: javascript, data-structures, priority-queue

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.values = []
  }
 enqueue(value, priority) {
  if(this.values.length === 0) {
      this.values.push({value: value, priority: priority})
      return this.values;
    }
    this.values.push({value, priority});
    this.bubbleUp(this.values); 
 }

 bubbleUp(values) {
    let childIndex = values.length-1;
    let parentIndex;
    parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex-1)/2); 
    let childNode, parentNode, temp;
    console.log(parentIndex, childIndex);
    console.log(values[parentIndex].priority, values[childIndex].priority)
    while ((values[childIndex].priority) < (values[parentIndex].priority)) {
      childNode = values[childIndex];
      parentNode = values[parentIndex];

      temp = childNode;
      childNode = parentNode;
      parentNode = temp;
      
      values[childIndex] = childNode;
      values[parentIndex] = parentNode;

      childIndex = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex-1)/2);
    }
    return values;
   }
}
```

The above is my implementation of priority queue using JavaScript.
I am storing the data in an array containing nodes that are objects like this
{value: "something", priority: 1}

When I try to add the second node using the enqueue method, I get an error in the `while` condition.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'priority')
```

I can clearly see the priority values of the nodes in the previous console.log statement. I am unable to figure out why the loop condition is failing with an error which says I am trying to read properties of undefined.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are not you getting `parentIndex = -1` on the second iteration of the loop? Child index is going to end up 0 at some point. I think you missed a condition to stop when there are no more nodes left.

Comment: No, I am not dequeueing yet, I am just adding nodes. I can clearly see the output of the console statement just before the while condition. You can copy this code and paste in jsfiddle or your browser and check.

Comment: You are logging before the loop, not inside of it.
You start with `parentIndex = 0` and `childIndex = 1`. The next time WHILE verifies whether it should continue or not, the `parentIndex` will already be `-1` (`Math.floor((0-1)/2)`) and you end up referencing `values` at a negative index. That is where you get an undefined, cause `values[-1] === undefined`.

Comment: I fixed the above by enclosing the last two line inside the while loop with an `if (parentIndex !==0)` , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```js
class Node {
    constructor(data, priority) {
      this.data = data;
      this.priority = priority;
    }
  }

class PQ {
  constructor() {
    //Initialing the array heap and adding a dummy element at index 0
    this.heap = [];
  }

  getMin() {
    //Accessing the min element at index 1 in the heap array
    return this.heap[0];
  }

  enqueue(data, priority) {
    let newNode = new Node(data, priority);
    this.heap.push(newNode);

    let currentIndex = this.heap.length - 1;
    let parentIndex = Math.round(currentIndex / 2) - 1;

    while (
      currentIndex > 0 &&
      this.heap[parentIndex].priority > this.heap[currentIndex].priority
    ) {
      [this.heap[parentIndex], this.heap[currentIndex]] = [
        this.heap[currentIndex],
        this.heap[parentIndex],
      ];

      currentIndex = parentIndex;
    }
  }

  dequeue() {
    //Smallest element is at the index 1 in the heap array
    let smallest = this.heap[0];

    if (this.heap.length === 1) {
      //If there are only two elements in the array, we directly splice out the first element
      this.heap.splice(0, 1);
    }

    //When there are more than two elements in the array, we put the right most element at the
    //first position and start comparing nodes with the child nodes
    if (this.heap.length >= 2) {
      this.heap[0] = this.heap[this.heap.length - 1];
      this.heap.splice(this.heap.length - 1);

      if (this.heap.length === 2) {
        if (this.heap[0].priority > this.heap[1].priority) {
          [this.heap[0], this.heap[1]] = [this.heap[1], this.heap[0]];
        }
        return smallest;
      }

      let current = 0;
      let leftChildIndex = current * 2 + 1;
      let rightChildIndex = current * 2 + 2;

      while (
        this.heap[leftChildIndex] &&
        this.heap[rightChildIndex] &&
        (this.heap[current].priority > this.heap[leftChildIndex].priority ||
          this.heap[current].priority > this.heap[rightChildIndex].priority)
      ) {
        if (this.heap[leftChildIndex].priority < this.heap[rightChildIndex].priority) {
          [this.heap[current], this.heap[leftChildIndex]] = [
            this.heap[leftChildIndex],
            this.heap[current],
          ];
          current = leftChildIndex;
        } else {
          [this.heap[current], this.heap[rightChildIndex]] = [
            this.heap[rightChildIndex],
            this.heap[current]
          ];
          current = rightChildIndex;
        }

        leftChildIndex = current * 2 + 1;
        rightChildIndex = current * 2 + 2;
      }
    }

    return smallest;
  }
}

const pq = new PQ();
pq.enqueue(3, 2);
pq.enqueue(4, 5);
pq.enqueue(31, 1);
pq.enqueue(6, 3);
console.log(pq.heap);
console.log(pq.dequeue());
console.log(pq.dequeue());
console.log(pq.dequeue());
console.log(pq.dequeue());
```